# How do I get rid of the banner on Bioacoustics beta?

Tags: feature-request, private-beta, notification-bar

[image: "...got a question about the site itself? bioacoustics.meta is the place to talk about..." banner at top of page]

I thought that visiting meta there might make the banner disappear when returning to the main site, but no.

Logging out and returning to the site didn't help either.

Please can we have a "close banner" button?

Answer (score 6):

I agree, these kind of banners should be dismissable, just like the current one for the Developer Survey results:

[image]

Alternatively, use a user style sheet through one of various browser plugins:

```css
aside.s-banner {
  display: none;
}
```

or an ad blocker with the following rule:

```
bioacoustics.stackexchange.com##aside.s-banner
```

And as you probably realized, the banner will disappear automatically after a while, around the time public beta begins.